# Using TP-Link TL-WDN-4800

Tags: wireless, 12.10

I am currently unable to run my newly obtained TP-Link TL-WDN-4800 wireless card with Ubuntu 12.10 and I'm currently unable to get it working.

I've tried `sudo modprobe ath9k`, and that didn't change anything, so I added `ath9k` to the end of `/etc/modules` and that didn't work. I stubled upon this tread [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1970955) and I treid the "fix" in post #2, but it didn't help.

What can I do to get it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working, after days of testing, it proved to be a faulty pci-e slot on my motherboard. Getting it fixed now. Sorry for the confusion.